# search not working with separate search model in yii2

Tags: search, yii2

I am new to yii2.I have created model,separate search model,views and controller using gii.There is search in my index form and it is not working.
Should i modify the code generated by gii to make it working?

My index view code is like this:

```
<?= GridView::widget([
    'dataProvider' => $dataProvider,
    'filterModel' => $searchModel,
    'columns' => [
        ['class' => 'yii\grid\SerialColumn'],

        'user_name',
        'eng_full_name',
        'phone',
        'mobile',
        'email:email',
        [
            'label' => 'Status',
            'attribute' => 'status',
            'value' => 'userStatus.cv_lbl',
        ],

        [
            'class' => 'yii\grid\ActionColumn',
            'contentOptions' => [
                'style' => 'width:80px;',
            ],
        ],
    ],
]) ?>
```

My controller:

```
public function actionIndex()
{
    $searchModel = new UserSearch();
    $dataProvider = $searchModel->search([Yii::$app->request->queryParams]);

    return $this->render('index', [
        'searchModel' => $searchModel,
        'dataProvider' => $dataProvider,
    ]);
}
```

My search model is:

```
public function rules()
{
    return [
        [['user_id', 'br_id', 'role_id', 'designation', 'created_by', 'updated_by', 'update_count', 'status', 'type'], 'integer'],
        [['user_name'],'string'],
        [['user_name', 'user_password', 'eng_full_name', 'nep_full_name', 'phone', 'mobile', 'email', 'remarks', 'created_dt', 'updated_dt'], 'safe'],
    ];
}

public function search($params)
{
    $query = UserAccounts::find();
    $dataProvider = new ActiveDataProvider([
        'query' => $query,
        'pagination' => array('pageSize' => 50),
    ]);

    if (!($this->load($params) && $this->validate())) {
       return $dataProvider;
    }

    $query->andFilterWhere([
        'designation' => $this->designation,
        'status' => $this->status,
        'type' => $this->type,
    ]);

    $query->andFilterWhere(['like', 'user_name', $this->user_name])
        ->andFilterWhere(['like', 'user_password', $this->user_password])
        ->andFilterWhere(['like', 'eng_full_name', $this->eng_full_name])
        ->andFilterWhere(['like', 'phone', $this->phone])
        ->andFilterWhere(['like', 'mobile', $this->mobile])
        ->andFilterWhere(['like', 'email', $this->email])
        ->andFilterWhere(['like', 'remarks', $this->remarks]);

    return $dataProvider;
}
```

My userAccounts model:

```
class UserAccounts extends ActiveRecord implements IdentityInterface
{
    public $username;
    public $user_password_repeat;
    public $old_password;

    public static function tableName()
    {
        return 'user_accounts';
    }

    public function rules()
    {
        return [
            [['user_name', 'user_password',  'role_id', 'eng_full_name',  'designation',   'status', 'user_password_repeat'], 'required'],
            [['br_id', 'role_id', 'designation', 'created_by', 'updated_by', 'update_count', 'status', 'type'], 'integer'],
            [['created_dt', 'updated_dt','user_password_repeat'], 'safe'],
            [['user_name', 'user_password', 'eng_full_name',  'email'], 'string', 'max' => 50],
            [['phone', 'mobile'], 'string', 'max' => 10],
            [['remarks'], 'string', 'max' => 500],
            [['user_name'], 'unique'],
            [['user_password'], 'compare'],
            ['old_password', 'required' ,'on' => 'changePassword'],
            ['old_password', 'compareCurrentPassword', 'on' => 'changePassword'],
        ];
    }

    public function attributeLabels()
    {
        return [
            'user_id' => 'User ID',
            'user_name' => 'user name',
            'user_password' => 'password',
            'user_password_repeat' =>'Confirm Password',
            'br_id' => 'Br ID',
            'role_id' => 'role id',
            'eng_full_name' => 'eng name',
            'phone' => 'phone',
            'mobile' => 'mobile',
            'designation' => 'designation',
            'email' => 'email',
            'remarks' => 'remarks',
            'created_by' => 'Created By',
            'created_dt' => 'Created Dt',
            'updated_by' => 'Updated By',
            'updated_dt' => 'Updated Dt',
            'update_count' => 'Update Count',
            'status' => 'Status',
            'type' => 'type',
            'old_password'=>'old password'
        ];
    }
}
```

Comment: normally using gii the search functionalities are immediatly available  .. no modifiy are needs .. what do you mean for not working .. you have error or  other. .. please  explaine  better your problem

Comment: I am wondering why my search is not wondering.search by any thing i.e. by name ,by phone,by email,by mobile not working and there are no any errors also

Comment: please update you question and add the related   model code

Comment: i have added search model code .

Comment: no search model .. but the model (i think is User Model .. )

Comment: i have added my useraccounts model

Comment: Why you have $username  in model and user_name  in table  .. why you are using two different element?   .. could be you are searching for username by you are user_name too and you do a mismatch?

Comment: i forgot to remove that declaration $username.i have removed that now

Comment: try clear the runtime  .. subdirectory .. in your app ..

Comment: u mean delete every thing from runtime folder

Comment: yes... sometime (if you change model) remain some old code  .. and the app don't work properly .... eventuallu perform a backup copy if you are worried

Comment: i tried as you said but still search not working

Comment: What happens when u type something in the grid view search input and click anywhere on the page page ? Is it refreshing ? Any J's error in console?

Comment: Is all fileds are not searchable??

Comment: yes search for all fields are not working

Comment: when i type any thing in grid view search input and click enter nothing is happening and there appears no error.its not refreshing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok I found the answer for my question.Sometimes jquery files included with in the project may cause such problems.There may be conflict between jquery files.In my case ,i had included jquery-2.2.3.min.js.When i removed that files Search is working properly.

Answer (score 1):

You are sending the search params incorrectly in your controller:

```
$dataProvider = $searchModel->search([Yii::$app->request->queryParams]);
```

You need to send them without the square brackets:

```
$dataProvider = $searchModel->search(Yii::$app->request->queryParams);
```